# Count all similar objects in a list

Tags: java, list

I have a list of Objects (they're not like this always, there's less or more, it depends)

```
[1xtile.air@0, 1xtile.air@0, 16xitem.enderPearl@0, 64xitem.eyeOfEnder@0, 16xitem.enderPearl@0, 64xitem.blazeRod@0, 1xitem.enchantedBook@0, 64xitem.blazeRod@0, 16xitem.enderPearl@0, 64xitem.eyeOfEnder@0, 16xitem.enderPearl@0]
```

Like you see most of them have the same name, this object has getCount() method which returns the amount of items in one object.
I was wondering how could I merge all the objects with same names (I get the object name with getUnlocalizedName()) but increase their count with getCount() of each object, so for example I have

```
[16xitem.enderPearl@0, 10xitem.enderPearl@, 1xtile.air@0]
```

First one's count is 16 and second 10 I would like to merge them together and get a list that looks like this: `[26xitem.enderPearl@0, 1xtile.air@0]`,
there's also setCount(int) method so that can be used to set the count on the new object.

I tried this (the list is called stacks and is like in that example above)

```
List<ItemStack> newStacks = Lists.newArrayList();
for (int index = 0; index < stacks.size(); index++) {
    ItemStack stack = stacks.get(index);
    ListIterator<ItemStack> iterator = stacks.listIterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        int index1 = iterator.nextIndex();
        ItemStack itemStack = iterator.next();
        if (index != index1 && stack.getUnlocalizedName().equals(itemStack.getUnlocalizedName())) {
            newStacks.removeIf(itemStack1 -> itemStack1.getUnlocalizedName().equals(itemStack.getUnlocalizedName()));
            stack.setCount(stack.getCount() + itemStack.getCount());
        }
    }
    newStacks.add(stack);
}
```

but I get `[36xitem.enderPearl@0, 1xtile.air@0]`

Comment: in your example 0th index value and the 1st index value is different.

Comment: Create a `Map<Item, Integer>`, key is for example `item.enderPearl@0`, value is `26`.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us **your** code!

Comment: What do you mean by similar? Did you try to use isIstanceOf?

Comment: updated with code, also I cannot use instanceof because its a same object just different name, count and some other data

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, the correct way to do it is by copying the itemstack (copy method copies all the data from the current ItemStack and returns a new one) from the list because it got changed in the list itself so on second iteration it added 10 from the second object to first object which was changed to 26 on first iteration.

```
List<ItemStack> newStacks = Lists.newArrayList();
    for (int index = 0; index < stacks.size(); index++) {
        ItemStack stack = stacks.get(index).copy();
        ListIterator<ItemStack> iterator = stacks.listIterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            int index1 = iterator.nextIndex();
            ItemStack itemStack = iterator.next();
            if (index != index1 && stack.getUnlocalizedName().equals(itemStack.getUnlocalizedName())) {
                newStacks.removeIf(itemStack1 -> itemStack1.getUnlocalizedName().equals(itemStack.getUnlocalizedName()));
                stack.grow(itemStack.getCount()); // the equivalent of stack.setCount(stack.getCount() + itemStack.getCount());
            }
        }
    }
newStacks.add(stack);
}
```